# Is Response.End() mandatory in the given scenario?

Tags: asp.net, response.write

```
string filePath = ExportAndSaveInvoiceAsHtml(invoiceId);      

Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + Path.GetFileName(filePath));

Response.WriteFile(filePath);

// Using Response.End() solves the problem
// Response.End();
```

I want to enable users to download HTML invoice (from gridView of invoices). The resulting file contains the invoice file data + unwanted the page html also.

If i use Response.End(), it solves the problem, but then it always throws exception. Read in some threads that exception is by design. But then is it sure, it wont cause problem like response truncation or so anytime ?

How else can i write JUST the file data.

Btw, earlier we wrote invoice as PDF, and that time not using Response.End() caused incomplete file download.

Can someone give basics of writing custom data/file to Response stream.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because the response is *buffered*. You have to call [Response.End()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.end.aspx) to flush the buffers and ensure the client gets the complete response before the handler thread completes.

The [ThreadAbortException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadabortexception.aspx) thrown by `Response.End()` is by design and can safely be ignored.

Comment: Well I have outer try block and now since this exception is ignorable i wrapped it inside dummy try
                {
                    Response.End();
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    Logger.LogException(ex);
                }

Comment: But its going into outer catch block also which has code to show error message to user.

Comment: @Munish, I'm afraid I don't understand: since you swallow the exception, it shouldn't propagate to the outer scope. (Also, you should catch `ThreadAbortException` instead of the generic `Exception` type).

Comment: Exactly. Exception should not propagate, but it seems to be doing so. let me test it once again and will put up the result.

Comment: I found a solution to this. It looks like the ThreadAbortException gets propegated upwards no matter what. Every level in the chain needs to catch (ThreadAbortException err) { } as well whatever exceptions they were already catching.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of Response.End() you can use

```
HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest()
```

This method tend to avoid throwing exceptions :)

Comment: I get Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'HttpContext' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Strange I had "using System.Web;" May be ambiguous name resolution problem. Anyway but compilation worked using full path. but functionality still the same. still coming as file + page data mix.